# Youtube api public comment spam

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

So I was making a little app to leave a funny comment on youtube videos posted by a channel (a fun gimmick common on the channel) so I used the youtube data api to detect when a video was uploaded and then comment on it. It worked however i noticed that my comment was only appearing to when I was logged into my account. Is this because of some spam filter? How/how long do I have to wait in my app to make a comment that wont be marked as spam?

Comment: Did you check the status of the comment if it is `publish`?

Comment: I'm not the owner of the channel/video, so how would I do that or change it if it isn't published?